# How to search for and show all .pdf files on USB-Stick in batch?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to search for .pdf files on usb-stick and to show them all in the cmd.

The following command in batch script doesn't bring any result:

```
for /r %%i in ( E:\*.pdf ) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%i
```

Comment: You might need to `cd /d E:\` instead of doing `in (E:\*.pdf)`.

Comment: @ender_scythe  how do you mean it? for /r %%i in ( cd /d E:.*pdf ) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%i

Comment: No, you first enter `cd /d E:\` before the `for`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, `for /r` accepts a pure file pattern within the parentheses:

```
for /r E:\ %%i in (*.pdf) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%~i
```

The root directory needs to be specified immmediately after the `/r` switch.

---

Alternatively, you can change the current working directory to the given root using `cd` and apply the `for /r` loop there:

```
cd /d E:\
for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%~i
```

To state all that in a single line, use:

```
cd /d E:\ & for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do echo %%~ti %%~zi %%~i
```